# Manually delete corrupt registry key not shown by regedit

Tags: registrykey

I have 2 registry keys that a scanner detects as a broken CLSID, but they don't show up in REGEDIT, possibly because their path is corrupt, for example...

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\etc
```

This should be...

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\etc
```

If they weren't referencing software that I am trying to run, I could ignore them, except theses keys are preventing an OCX from being from being detected and run.

Creating a .reg file with a minus (-) like..

```
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID]
```

does not remove the key. Nor can it be edited this way... regedit ignores this file but it is still there and it's still affecting plugin detection!

Using DOS Command-line like...

```
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESOFTWARE
```

only returns "Invalid key name"!

Where and how can I remove/edit these corrupted keys?

Answer (score 1):

You have to take ownership of that key and all sub keys. Right click on the key and choose PERMISSIONS and take ownership of the key and then just delete it. I know this post is a year old but this might help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting it [with RawReg](http://reboot.pro/files/file/95-rawreg/), a free, from-scratch implementation of a registry editor, i.e. it does not use the registry APIs, which means it shouldn't have the same issue.

FYI: RawReg has its own host of issues and bugs, though.

Comment: It cannot find the registry hive in Windows Server 2008.